# @SpyBean with few Integration tests doesn't work correctly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I have a strange behavior of @SpyBean field in my integration tests.
For example, I have a few integration tests:

```
package a;

@SpringBootTest
public class A {
 @SpyBean
 public MySpyBeanCandidate spyBean;

 @Test
 public void test1 {
   // some work
   Mockito.verify(spyBean, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).methodName(eq("String value"), anyString());
 }

}
```

```
package a;

@SpringBootTest
public class B {
 @SpyBean
 public MySpyBeanCandidate spyBean;

 @Test
 public void test2 {
   // some work
   Mockito.verify(spyBean, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).methodName(eq("String value"), anyString());
 }

}
```

The problem is when I try to execute them separately they executed successfully, but if I'll run them together, in the second test Mockito.verify(..) will throw an exception: `Wanted but not invoked`. But I have debugged it and checked that method (`methodName`) called correctly. Who knows why this is happening?

Comment: It's hard to say you don't provide enough code. Is the method really called as expected when both are run? The test setup and production code is missing.

Comment: @DCTID, thanks for the response! "Is the method really called as expected when both are run?", yes and in the second method ```spyBean``` it's really mock, but nothing doesn't happen, just ```Wanted but not invoked```.
"The test setup and production code is missing." - what do you mean? It's the correct code.

Comment: Try to provide an [mre]. As it is currently we can not tell you what is going wrong as we are not able to reproduce this behaviour based on the code you have posted.

Comment: What I mean by the test setup and production code is missing is, `MySpyBeanCandidate` is not supplied. You're spying so the actual code is important. Also, you just wrote `//some work` for however you call, mock etc the `spyBean`. We couldn't copy paste you code into our ide and see the same results that you are.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

`@DirtiesContext` on each `@Test` method for such cases worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me helped the next lines:

```java
    @AfterEach
    public void resetSpy() {
        reset(spyBean);
    }
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#can-i-reset-a-mock):

> the mock forgot any interactions and stubbing