# @SpyBean doesn't intercept method calls when test class isn't executed separately

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have multiple `@WebMvcTest`-annotated test classes that run successfully if executed separately (e.g. via `mvn -Dtest=BTest test` or via IDE).

However if they'are executed together (e.g. via `mvn test` or `mvn package`) one test fails (`BTest` in the below code) because `@SpyBean`-annotated field doesn't intercept method calls. The other tests don't have any `@SpyBean`'s.

The corresponding code structure is below:

```
// ATest.java
@WebMvcTest
class ATest {
   ...
}

// BTest.java
@WebMvcTest
class BTest {

    ...

    @SpyBean
    private ComponentToSpyOn comp;

    ...

    @Test
    void testSomething() {

        ...

        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Mockito.doAnswer(inv -> {
            var result = inv.callRealMethod();
            latch.countDown();
            return result;
        }).when(comp).execute(any());
            
        // Execute something that would lead to call interception

        // Wait for method return
        if (!latch.await(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            latch = null;
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }

       ...

    }
}

// CTest.java
@WebMvcTest
class CTest {
   ...
}
```

I've tried to apply `@DirtiesContext` on the affected test class and its methods according to the recommendation here [@SpyBean with few Integration tests doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776044/spybean-with-few-integration-tests-doesnt-work-correctly) but with no result.

As the `@SpyBean` isn't null and doesn't intercept method call it must be initialized somehow incorrectly.

I've solved the problem with Maven configuration as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68619944/971355
Each test on a separate VM but I don't like the solution as it slows down the test execution for sure.